# In Sitecore Personalize, how can I use HTML passed from a decision model as HTML in a web experience?

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize

I have created a web experience that is using a decision model. My decision model is returning HTML and I want this to be used as HTML in my web experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually if you are returning a property from a decision model to a web experience (e.g. string, Boolean, integer), you need to return that property in the API tab of the web experience and then reference that the property in the HTML tab using:

```
 {{#attribute}}
```

If you are returning HTML from a decision model to a web experience, you need to return that property in the API tab and then reference that the property in the HTML tab using:

```
 {{{#attribute}}}
```

[image]